# Implementing custom bottom tab bar curved outcrop in React native

Tags: react-native

What I [need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gp28.png)

What I [have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laCk7.png)

I'm struggling to create the smooth blend curve at the intersection of the outcropping and the bottom bar. I found examples of inset curves but I those are not helpful in this case.

What can I do to achieve that effect? To be clear, I am talking about the smooth curve at the active tab element and the navigation bar and not about the bottom left and right radius of the navigation bar.

EDIT: added more info and marked images for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Add following Radius to your bottom navbar main view

```
borderBottomLeftRadius:10,
borderBottomRightRadius:10,
```

Comment: If my answer is correct accept my  answer and it will help to others also.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Please check the new images.